# How to implement AbstractWebdriverEventListener in a script

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I have created a file with the name `SeleniumTestListener.java` and I have written the below code:

```
@override
@AfterMethod(alwaysrun=true)
public class UITestNGListener  extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener
{   

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        @Override
        @AfterTest(alwaysRun=true)
        public void onException(Throwable exception, WebDriver driver) {
        System.out.println("Failed Failed Failed");

    }
```

Now when I am trying to run the script(purposely making it to fail after login into my application)

But it is failing with a configuration issue

> org.testng.TestNGException: 
>   Method onException requires 2 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Configuration annotation.

Can someone please help how to pass the values(throwable exception, webdriver driver) for this?

Thanks much for the help

Comment: which version of test NG are you using?Have youspecified the listener name in @listener annotation in ur test class?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use `@AfterMethod` on a class.
2. If you specify parameters in a test method, you need to pass these parameters either with the `@Parameters` annotation or by using a `@DataProvider`.